# Limit of normal hazard rate

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to work out the asymptotic behavior of the normal hazard rate as $x$ gets very large.  To be clear, that's the behavior of

$$ h(x) = \frac{ \phi(x)}{1-\Phi(x)} \qquad \text{ as } \qquad x \rightarrow \infty$$

Where $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the pdf and cdf respectively of the standard normal.

I don't think anyone on this site or elsewhere online has addressed this question specifically.  The closest I found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167560/the-limit-of-hazard-rate-hx-a-1-b-as-x-approaches-pm-infty), but that is much more general than what I want.

In the limit, this looks like it is linear (picture below), but I can't quite show why or to what limit.  Both numerator and denominator go to 0 as $x$ gets very large.

My best attempt at figuring this out was to apply L'Hopital's rule.

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} h(x) &= \frac{ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \phi'(x) }{ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} -\phi(x)} \\
                                 &= \frac{ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} -x \phi(x) }{ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} -\phi(x)} 
\end{align*}

This still fails as both the top and bottom converge to zero.    The limits don't exist, so I'm no good here.

Now I **know** that the next line is not ok, but I tried it anyway, because I had no better ideas.  What if I "cancel" the $\phi(\cdot)$ functions in the numerator and denominator?  That is, I tried the following:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} h(x) \overset{?}{=} x$$

It turns out that this is a pretty good approximation to the limiting behavior. See the picture below ($h(x)$ solid, candidate $h'(x)$ dashed).  But I haven't **proved** anything, which is annoying.  It also turns out that this limit doesn't work in some other applications (not discussed here!).

[image: Normal hazard rate and candidate limit]

So, to summarize my questions:

- What is the asymptotic behavior of the normal hazard rate?  I couldn't find a reference.
- Is $h'(x)=x$ in the limit?
- If so, why?  My abuse of L'Hopital's rule isn't the reason.

Comment: Is $h(x)$ the same function from the linked question?

Comment: Actually, which function making up h(x) are you using? It's kind of relevant...

Comment: I'm using the one defined at the top of *this* question - the hazard rate for the standard normal.  The linked question is much more general; it is for an arbitrary density.  I'm not interested in general results, just the normal.

Comment: My question is valid, they aren't defined. They're implied to equal something that I can't figure out. What is $\phi(x)$ and what is $\Phi(x)$? I suppose they both aren't equal to the normal distribution...

Comment: I see - sorry.  $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the pdf and cdf respectively of the standard normal.  I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to consider the standard normal distribution, as any other univariate normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ can be standardized by a suitable location-scale transformation.  Thus we have $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}, \quad -\infty < x < \infty,$$ and $$F(x) = \int_{z=-\infty}^x f(z) \, dz.$$  Then the hazard rate is $$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)},$$ and the limit by L'Hopital's rule is $$\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{-f(x)},$$ as you observed.  Now $$f'(x) = -x f(x),$$ hence we simply have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} x = \infty.$$  It is easy to see that the hazard is asymptotic to $x$ for large $x$.  It is not too difficult to obtain an asymptotic series expansion about $x = \infty$:  $$h(x) = x + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{10}{x^5} + O(x^{-7}).$$  Perhaps surprisingly, $$h(x) \approx \frac{x + \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$$ is also an excellent approximation, certainly better for "small" $x$ than the asymptotic series above.

Comment: So more generally, if the density satisfies some first-order differential equation (as in this case, $f' = xf$), we can use that to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)$?

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.  Thanks very much.  A few follow-up questions:

1) My use of L'hopital's rule in the question is wrong.  I thought I was being careful, but I was just being wrong.  Should I correct it to improve the question, or leave it as a matter of record?
2) The asymptotic expansion may not be "not too difficult to obtain" for you, but it certainly is for me.  :)  I'm familiar with expansions around a finite point, but not with expansions at infinity.  Where can I look this up?
3) Where does the final approximation come from?  Just another Taylor series approx near the origin?

Comment: A more substantive question: Is the use of L'Hopital's rule acceptable here at all?  The usage of the rule requires that the limit of the ratio of differentials exists.  Here it is infinite, which I think does not count as a limit (i.e. given $\delta$ you can't find $\epsilon$ s.t. $x-\infty<\delta \ \forall \ x > \infty-\epsilon$).  Is that correct?

Comment: @squipbar Zach here again. Yes, you can't apply L'Hopital without indeterminate forms such as ${0 \over 0}$ or ${{\infty} \over {\infty}}$, which were present. It probably would've helped if I'd have told you that earlier...either way, you did end up with one term of the expansion.

Comment: @heropup, thank you a lot for your answer, but could you please elaborate a bit on the asymptotic expansion of hazard rate at $x = \infty$, how can one obtain it?

Answer (score 6):

A lower bound for the hazard is $h(s)>s,s>0$. I have established an upper bound, which might be new.

For $s>0$,
$$
h\left( s\right) <\frac{1}{%
s}+s.
$$
**Proof:** 
Note that
$$
-\left[ \phi _{0}\left( s\right) \frac{s}{1+s^{2}}%
\right] ^{\prime }=\phi _{0}\left( s\right) \left[ 1-2\frac{1}{%
\left( s^{2}+1\right) ^{2}}\right]
$$
and that
$$
1-2\frac{1}{\left( t^{2}+1\right) ^{2}}<1.
$$
Then
$$
\phi _{0}\left( s\right) \frac{s}{1+s^{2}}%
=\int_{s}^{\infty }\phi _{0}\left( t\right) \left( 1-2\frac{1}{%
\left( t^{2}+1\right) ^{2}}\right) dt<1-\Phi_{0}\left(
s\right) .
$$
The conclusion follows since $s>0$ implies that $\frac{s}{1+s^{2}}>0$.

**Remark** This improves the bound $h(s)<\frac{s^3}{s^2 -1}$ provided by Feller (1957) Lemma 2, Chapter VII.